# how to run flyway operations in tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, flyway

I have a spring boot application. Because of an upgrade I must update the migration files to make them compatible to the new version. This leads to hash mismatch and the application does not start. Locally I can fix it by running

```
mvn flyway:repair
```

However, in the servers the applications run in a tomcat, so I cannot execute those maven targets.

Is there another way to execute the flyway repair in an application running in tomcat?

Comment: Do you already have flyway-core dependency?

Comment: yes I have it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question was answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38577633/16398766

In short though, you create a `FlywayMigrationStrategy` bean in Spring to run the `flyway.repair()` method before your migrations.

Comment: Won't that fail on the start up with hash mismatch? I presumed that the code execution, happens after the migrations.

Comment: I will try it, if it works my question is a duplicate indeed.

Comment: If you create your own FlywayMigrationStrategy it overrides the one created by spring boot. So if you do flyway.repair() then flyway.migrate() in the method then it'll happen in that order.