# How to run flyway command in a spring boot application in k8s

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, flyway

Background: Now I have deployed a spring boot application in K8s. This application uses flyway-maven-plugin to manage database. The database is also deployed in K8s.

Issues: In some cases, when I start the application in K8s, there are errors that were caused by flyway and I need to use 'flyway repair'. The question is, how can I run the flyway command now? Should I enter the pod and find some dir level to run it?

I have tried to enter the pod and use maven:flyway repair but it failed (Can't find related command).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flyway repair with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462550/flyway-repair-with-spring-boot)